# Batch calls admin batch, vabiable doesn't cross over

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to send a variable from one batch file to another after elevating privileges. `Test2.bat` doesn't `echo` `test123`, it just `echo`s that `ECHO is on.`

**test1.bat**

```
set "test=test123"
call "%cd%\test2.bat"
pause
```

**test2.bat**

```
:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------

echo %test%
pause
```

Comment: Is this to put in place of batchgotadmin in test2.bat, or is it a different way to call test2.bat? My plan is to have a batch like test2.bat I can call from other batch files, those which contain things I don't want to run as admin.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a variable, then you are elevating and creating a new process and you expect the variable to exist. instead call `test2.bat` from `test1.bat` but let it set the variable after it got the privileges, but returning to call `test1.bat`..

```
@echo off
set "test=test123"
if not "%~1" == "haveAdmin" call "%~dp0\test2.bat"
```

then `test2.bat` some minor changes, see if you can spot them:

```
@echo off
:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else (
    goto gotAdmin
)

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%~dp0"
    call test1.bat haveAdmin
:--------------------------------------
echo %test%
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your code fails because the VBScript is creating a new separate process when prompting UAC.

If you only want to pass *one single variable* with *very simple content* (without embedded `'`, `"`, CRLF...), the easiest way is to pass as it as a parameter.

## test-call.bat

```dos
@echo off
set "test=test_123!" only works for simple content
call "%__CD__%admin.bat" %test%
```

## admin.bat

```dos
@echo off


if "%~1" == "" exit /b 1
("%__APPDIR__%net.exe" session||(
    "%__APPDIR__%WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command "Start-Process -FilePath '%~f0' -ArgumentList '%~1' -Verb Runas"
    exit /b
))>nul 2>&1


set "var=%~1"
====SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
echo(!var!
pause
```

If your code involves parsing multiple (all) variables or tricky content, the best way is to let `Start-Process` return to the [caller](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=41538&sid=7b3ed207a16cd93e9cdecb6287b195fb#p41538) itself.

Answer (score -2):

How about passing the batch file as parameter?

**Test1.bat**

```
set "test=test123"
 "%cd%\test2.bat" "%test%"
pause
```

**Test2.bat**

```
@echo off
set "test=%~1"
:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------

echo %test%
pause
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I still only get "ECHO is on". Test2.bat does this:
    set "test="

Comment: @unknownsoldierx This should work, maybe try without call like `"%cd%\test2.bat" "%test%"`